# using two different types of woods for outdoor pergola

Tags: wood, outdoor

Is it okay to use two different types of woods for building a pergola?

I was thinking about using 6x6 pecky cedar for pergola posts and use redwood for beams and rafters. Is this considered Ok?

Comment: Just for future reference, questions about structures are more appropriate for the "DIY" stackexchange site.

Answer (score 2):

I see absolutely no reason not to do this.

There are some rare circumstances where the different expansion/contraction rates of different woods can cause issues (i.e. a checkerboard end-grain cutting board), but for construction purposes you can generally mix and match species however you see fit.

Comment: +1. And in fact in many locales this mixing of species will happen incidentally in certain projects because for example a 2x12 is frequently a different species to smaller 2x material.